# I cannot seem to get key press handling working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have viewed many answered questions on StackOverflow and have implemented the code I have found what I thought was correctly but I cannot get my character to move with a keyboard press. What is the problem here?

Javascript file

```
var key = []; 

document.addEventListener('keydown',
    function(e){
        handleKeyPress(e);
});


onkeydown = onkeyup = function(e){
    e = e || event;
    map[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';
    if (key[65]){ //'a' is pressed
        if (crxpos > 8)
            crxpos-=8;
    }
    else if (key[68]){ //'d' is pressed
        if (crxpos < 1280 - 40)
                crxpos+=8;
    }
    else if (key[83]){ //'s' is pressed
        if (crypos < 720 - 40)
                crypos+=8;
    }
    else if (key[87]){ //'w' is pressed
        if (crypos > 8)
                crypos-=8;
    }
}
var map = document.getElementById("map");
var ctx = map.getContext("2d");
var dt = 1000 / 30.0;

var caverunner = new Image();
caverunner.src = "caverunner.png";
caverunner.addEventListener("load", drawImage);
var crxpos = 1280 / 2 - 4;
var crypos = 720 / 2 - 4;

function drawImage(){
    setInterval(update, dt);
}

function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1280, 720);
    ctx.drawImage(caverunner, crxpos, crypos);
}
```

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css" media="all"> @import "canvas.css"; </style>
<body>

<h1>Cave</h1>
<canvas id="map" width="1280" height="720" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<p> </p>
<script src="cave.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you binding the key events and to what element? `onkeydown = onkeyup = function(e){` only defines a variable. You need to bind the event to an element.

Comment: Please read about event listeners and how they work. You must specify an element to listen for your key presses. [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: So I have read that page you linked and have a good feel for how these event listeners work but am still a little bit confused. My best guess for what my program needs is somewhere I need to add a line of code     e.addeventlistener("somethinghere") I'm not sure what goes in the quoted and I am not sure where to put it in my code, any ideas?

Comment: Also I am editing my code in the post to show my latest attempt!

Comment: This is as far as I have gotten with using event listeners and my code isn't working, any help?